# Pyspark UDF using Quantlib function

Tags: pyspark, quantlib

I have been experimenting with Quantlib and Spark, trying to pass a Quantlib function in Pyspark see example below:

```
from QuantLib import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf


df = sc.parallelize([("2016-10-01",),
                     ("2016-11-01",),
                     ("2016-12-01",)]).toDF(['someDate'])

testudf = udf(lambda x: str(DateParser.parseFormatted(x,'%Y-%m-%d')), StringType())

df.withColumn('new', testudf('someDate')).show()
```

I haven't been successful so far and was wondering if anybody has had better luck.

Here is the error I get:

```
typeError: in method 'DateParser_parseFormatted', argument 1 of type 'std::string const &'
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
```

Comment: ....and how, exactly, have you not been successful?

Comment: What's the exact type of the `x` that gets passed to the lambda inside `udf`? Is it a Python string, or some Spark type?

Comment: X would be a spark string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being exported from C++, the `DateParser.parseFormatted` method is kind of particular about types and can't take the Spark string `x` that the udf machinery is passing to the lambda.  You'll have to convert `x` back to a Python string inside the lambda. I'm not familiar with Spark and its types, but maybe `str(x)`, as in

```
lambda x: str(DateParser.parseFormatted(str(x), '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

might do the work?

As a side note, I'm not sure what's the point of the outer `str` in your lambda.  You're taking a string, converting it to a `Date` object by means of `DateParser`, and then you're converting the result to a string again...